# Convert Time to Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a column in a dataframe that contains time in the below format.

```
Dataframe: df
column: time
value: 07:00:00, 13:00:00 or 14:00:00
```

The column will have only one of these three values in each row. I want to convert these to 0, 1 and 2. Can you help replace the times with these numeric values?

Current:

```
df['time'] = [07:00:00, 13:00:00, 14:00:00]
```

Expected:

```
df['time'] = [0, 1, 2]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us the Python version you're using - tags indicate both 2.7 and 3, while some things are incompatible between those.

Comment: In general, mapping the strings shown in your example to int 1,2,3 doesn't make much sense to me. Please consider using `datetime` data type, for pandas df see e.g. [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to do this:

```
import datetime

mapping = {datetime.time(07,00,00):0, datetime.time(13,00,00):1, datetime.time(14,00,00):2}
df['time']=df['time'].map(mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `map`

**Ex:**

```
val = {"07:00:00":0, "13:00:00":1, "14:00:00":2}

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':["07:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00"] })
df["time"] = df["time"].map(val)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   time
0     0
1     1
2     2
```